# Why do we not consider the case where $u$ and $v$ in the factored form $(x+u)(x+v)$ are fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

When factoring the quadratic $x^2 + bx + c $, where $b$ and $c$ are integers, why do we not consider the case where $u$ and $v$ in the factored form $(x+u)(x+v)$ are fractions?

We wish to write this as $(x + u) (x + v)$. Where $u = \frac{p}{q}$ and $v =\frac{m}{n}$.

\begin{align}
\left(x + \frac{p}{q}\right)\left(x + \frac{m}{n}\right)&= x\left(x+\frac{m}{n}\right)+\frac{p}{q}\left(x + \frac{m}{n}\right)\\
&=x^2 + \frac{mx}{n} + \frac{px}{q} + \frac{pm}{qn}\\
&=qnx^2 + (mq + pn)x + pm.
\end{align}

This is quite different from the quadratic $x^2 + bx + c$.

Am I along the right path? What's the complete reasoning?

Comment: Your last equality is of the form $A=qnA$ which in general is false. You need to multiply *both* sides of the equation by $qn$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $u = \frac{p}{q}$ and $v = \frac{m}{n}$ for some integers $p,q,m,n$ then you obtain the equation $$qn\left(x + \frac{p}{q}\right)\left(x + \frac{m}{n}\right) = qnx^2 + (mq + pn)x + pm.$$  In the expression $qnx^2 + (mq + pn)x + pm$ we can conclude that $qn, mq+pn$, and $pm$ are all integers.  If we use the labels

\begin{align}a &= qn\\
b&=mq+pn\\
c&=pm\\
u &= \frac{p}{q}\\
v &= \frac{m}{n}\end{align} then we again end up with $$(x-u)(x-v) = ax^2 + bx + c,$$ so in reality this form covers your case as well.  Generally, though, we don't require $a,b,c,u,v$ to be integers.

Comment: So do you mean fractions are also ok in factored form?

Comment: Yes, they don't even need to be real numbers, actually.  For example $(x^2 + 1) = (x + i)(x-i).$

Comment: When the topic of factorising quadratics is introduced, it's mostly for the sake of convenience of calculation that integer roots are chosen.